# dojox/charting/Chart2D : how to format the label of minor tick?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting

I am using **dojo Chart2D** to plot a graph having milliseconds values along the X axis. To display the minor tick values I want to convert the *milliseconds value* to *hh:mm:ss:msec* format. I can do it easily overriding *tickFormat()* method in D3. But I am stuck here with Chart2D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While adding the axis to the chart, we can use the attribute "labelFunc" which should be function taking 3 arguments:

1) `text` is the already pre-formatted text. Pre-formatting is done using `dojo/number` is available, `Date.toFixed` otherwise.

2) `value`  is the raw axis value.

3) `precision` is the requested precision to be applied.
and returns the label. eg:

```
chart.addAxis("x", {
    ...,
    labelFunc: function(text, value, precision) {
        return "axisLabel";
    }
});
```